# does MFC/C++ software run on a thin client

Tags: client, thin

a client ask me, if he can run my software on a thin client. My software is written in MFC/C++ and runs on Windows Vista/XP/7.
Does anybody know, if the client can install the software on the server and run it on his thin client's? If not, does anybody know any links, where it is described how to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of thin client it is, but look at [Microsoft RemoteApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055.aspx) or [Citrix XenApp](http://www.citrix.com/products/xenapp/overview.html).